# Blender Shifts Audio Sometimes

Tags: edit-mode, video, audio

I apologize for the lack of information; I am new to Blender and am unsure why this is happening. I recently started using Blender for video editing as I wanted an open-source video editor. In general, it does an amazing job. I keep running into a big issue with is causing me not to use it, though.

When editing clips, sometimes, for no reason, Blender moves the audio track from the position where I clipped it. For example, if I have a video where someone is talking, and I clip just one scene from their speech and then edit other clips and come back to that scene, the audio would have shifted to a different point in the video where it was split.

I have no idea why this is happening, and it is driving me crazy. I just spent all day on something and didn't even want to restart as this is the second time it has done this. Does anyone know what may be causing this? I am on Blender 2.90. I do have av-sync on.

This could be how I am using, but I am just so new to Blender I have no idea.

SOLUTION:
Frame rate! When I was importing video clips from different sources it skewed the frame rate, use handbrake to fix it.

Comment: Great you solved it :) Can you write "solution" as regular Answer? Thank you (or hide entire question). Thank you

Comment: @vklidu I added the answer :3

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this issue is to make sure you use consistent frame rates. One of the videos I pulled in changed the frame rate from 30 FPS to a custom frame rate which screwed the other clips. Setting the frame rate back to 20 FPS fixed this issue for me. I know you can use handbrake to set all of your videos to the same frame rate; however, if you are like me and just want a simple solution of

```
setfps <video-name> <frame-rate>
```

or at least a handbrake-like program that uses mpv for previews instead of VLC, I am unsure what program to use.

As an update, [you can use FFmpeg to reencode a framerate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462731/using-ffmpeg-to-change-framerate/45465730)!